# Universal App is being tested in Iphone compatibility mode by apple

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have (now) marked my app to be a Universal App.
When i deploy it locally to an ipad it runs as a native iPad app (all good, nice rendering, heaps of space)

when i submit it to Apple for review they reject it becasue they run it in iphone compatibility app (basically like an iphone 4 ) and the rendering goes wrong (not enough space).

What else do i need to set in the Xamarin project so it will never run in iPhone compatibility mode on the iPad ?

Comment: Do you only want to develop an iPad project? If so, try to modify the `Devices` to iPad in info.plist. Then when you submit to apple store, the auditor will not check it on iPhone devices.

Comment: no i would like to have a Universal app.
but it turned out to be my fault because i didn't know how to drive itunesconnect..

Answer (score 0):

turns out the itunesconnect site is realy not that user friendly...apple eh..
i found a way to delete the old build and link to the new build and they approved it
funny thing is that they seem to write the version of what you enter in itunes connect into your app. so even though they were testing an old build, the screenshot was showing the new build version.. very confusing